# Deploying web app using Ant results in NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

I'm using Ant 1.9.3 and Tomcat version 8.0. I'm using the Ant `deploy` target to deploy web apps in the Apache Tomcat using the `manager` credentials. The `deploy` target fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 org/apache/tomcat/util/codec/binary/Base64
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalina
Task.java:204)
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask.execute(DeployTask.java:196)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary
.Base64
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 19 more
```

When I tried to find the class `Base64` in the package `org\apache\tomcat\util\codec\binary\` which is in `tomcat-util.jar`, and it is in the classpath which I've verified by an echo in Ant build file.

I'm not able to solve the issue.

Comment: You need to supply the ANT that your are using for us to troubleshoot your issue. You state the jar is on the classpath, but the JVM error states otherwise. I suspect it an issue with the way the tomcat "deploy" task has been declared in your build.

Comment: I am also having this problem with 1.9.4. I have added the text from the answer below to my build.xml file, in the path section, but am getting exactly the same error as before. I am not sure how to look inside of the tomcat-util.jar file, as the OP did, without getting a bunch of what I assume is Java bytecode, so I don't know how to verify. Here is a [link](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html) to the tutorial I'm using. There are a couple of subtle versioning errors I forged through; this one comes toward the bottom, when the user is asked to call `ant list`.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone runs into the same problem I was having:

I was following the tutorial on the [Tomcat website](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/appdev/index.html) and I ran into the same `NoClassDefFoundError` issue when I tried to run `ant install`.

The tutorial mentions that you have to copy `$CATALINA_HOME/lib/catalina-ant.jar`<sup>1</sup> (which contains the implementation code for the Ant custom tasks)  to the `lib` directory of your Ant installation.

It **does not** mention, however, that you need to do the same thing for `tomcat-util.jar`. As soon as I copied `tomcat-util.jar` to my Ant directory, things started working ([source](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201403.mbox/%3CBLU172-W1742A2B8B660341762C324AE610@phx.gbl%3E)).

<sup>1</sup>`$CATALINA_HOME` is the directory of your Tomcat installation, e.g. `/usr/share/tomcat8`

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have added the tomcat-util.jar in the classpath as below.

```
<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
    <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
        <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```